# jQuery array of inputs, add values

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, addition

Consider dozens of input like the ones bellow.  I need do subtract GLOSA and add AJUSTE from VALAUT and put the result in APAGAR, in each line individually, as the user type new values in GLOSA and AJUSTE.

```
<input type="hidden" id="valaut[]" name="valaut[0]" value="100" />
<input type="text"   id="glosa[]"  name="glosa[0]"  value="10" />
<input type="text"   id="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[0]" value="5" />
<input type="text"   id="apagar[]" name="apagar[0]" value="0" />
<br/>
<input type="hidden" id="valaut[]" name="valaut[1]" value="200" />
<input type="text"   id="glosa[]"  name="glosa[1]"  value="0" />
<input type="text"   id="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[1]" value="0" />
<input type="text"   id="apagar[]" name="apagar[1]" value="0" />
```

I´ve tryed many approaches, like this http://jsfiddle.net/rve232g8/ , but did not succeeded.

Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` wildcard as the selector.

```js
$('[name^=glosa], [name^=ajuste]').bind("change keyup input", function() {
  //Get the group number
  var group = $(this).attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];

  //Get the values
  var valaut = $('[name="valaut[' + group + ']"]').val();
  var glosa = $('[name="glosa[' + group + ']"]').val();
  var ajuste = $('[name="ajuste[' + group + ']"]').val();

  //Check if number
  if (!isNaN(valaut) && !isNaN(glosa) && !isNaN(ajuste)) {

    //Calculate apagar 
    var apagar = Number(valaut) - Number(glosa) + Number(ajuste);

    //Set value for apagar
    $('[name="apagar[' + group + ']"]').val(apagar);
  } else {
    //Some input non numbers. Clear the apagar
    $('[name="apagar[' + group + ']"]').val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="valaut[]" name="valaut[0]" value="100" />
<input type="text" id="glosa[]" name="glosa[0]" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[0]" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="apagar[]" name="apagar[0]" value="0" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" id="valaut[]" name="valaut[1]" value="200" />
<input type="text" id="glosa[]" name="glosa[1]" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[1]" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="apagar[]" name="apagar[1]" value="0" />
```

**Note:** I'm not entirely sure if the formula I used is accurate on what you need. You might want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet, using jQuery, which should fulfills your needs:
(See the comments in my snippet)

```js
// Update function
function update() {
  var valaut, glosa, ajuste;
  // For each "apagar", do the following:
  $('input[name^=apagar]').each(function(index) {
    // Get values
    valaut = $('input[name^=valaut]')[index].value;
    glosa = $('input[name^=glosa]')[index].value;
    ajuste = $('input[name^=ajuste]')[index].value;
    // Store the result (calculation using unary operator)
    $(this).val(+valaut - +glosa + +ajuste);
  });
}

// Launch function on load
update();
// Bind update function on inputs changes
$('input[name^=glosa], input[name^=ajuste]').on('keyup', update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="valaut[]" name="valaut[0]" value="100" disabled/>
<input type="text" class="glosa[]" name="glosa[0]" value="10" />
<input type="text" class="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[0]" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="apagar[]" name="apagar[0]" value="0" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="valaut[]" name="valaut[1]" value="200" disabled/>
<input type="text" class="glosa[]" name="glosa[1]" value="0" />
<input type="text" class="ajuste[]" name="ajuste[1]" value="0" />
<input type="text" class="apagar[]" name="apagar[1]" value="0" />
<br />
<p><u>Comments:</u><br /> Changed id to class in the inputs, as ids must be unique.<br /> Removed "hidden" and added "disabled" to see the "valauts" for testing.</p>
```

Edit: I added the use of the unary operator, as it makes the code really easier!
Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In both solutions, by @Edie and @Takit Isy I got the exact result I needed.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You should delete this, as it's not an answer! :) Please also review my updated answer, the code is now easier.